# How to remove rows in pandas of type datetime64[ns] by date?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

I'm pretty newbie, started to use python for my project.
I have dataset, first column has `datetime64[ns]` type

```
     <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
     RangeIndex: 5889 entries, 0 to 5888
     Data columns (total 3 columns):
      #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
     ---  ------  --------------  -----         
      0   date    5889 non-null   datetime64[ns]
      1   title   5889 non-null   object        
      2   stock   5889 non-null   object        
     dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), object(2)
     memory usage: 138.1+ KB
```

and

```
type(BA['date'])
```

gives

```
pandas.core.series.Series
```

date has format 2020-06-10
I need to delete all instances before specific date, for example 2015-09-09

What I tried:

1. convert to string. Failed
2. Create conditions using:

> ```
> .df.year <= %y & .df.month <= %m
> <= ('%y-%m-%d')
> create data with datetime() method
> create variable with datetime64 format
> ```

3. just copy with .loc() and .copy()

All of this failed, I had all kinds of error, like it's not int, its not datetime, datetime mutable, not this, not that, not a holy cow

How can this pandas format can be more counterintuitive, I can't believe, for first time I feel like write a parser CSV in C++ seems easier than use prepared library in python

Thank you for understanding

Comment: are you looking for [Filtering Pandas DataFrames on dates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22898824/10197418)? or [python pandas dataframe slicing by date conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16175874/10197418)?

Comment: _All of this failed, I had all kinds of error, like it's not int, its not datetime, datetime mutable, not this, not that, not a holy cow_ Can you share some details on those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Toy Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2021-1-1', '2020-12-6', '2019-02-01', '2020-02-01']})
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df
```

**Input df**

```
    date
0   2021-01-01
1   2020-12-06
2   2019-02-01
3   2020-02-01
```

Delete rows before `2020.01.01`.
We are selecting the rows which have dates after `2020.01.01` and ignoring old dates.

```
df.loc[df.date>'2020.01.01']
```

**Output**

```
    date
0   2021-01-01
1   2020-12-06
3   2020-02-01
```

**If we want the index to be reset**

```
df = df.loc[df.date>'2020.01.01']
df
```

**Output**

```
    date
0   2021-01-01
1   2020-12-06
2   2020-02-01
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe, but this works